# How to find increasing interval of function $|x-1|+x^2$

Tags: functions, derivatives

I  recently came across a function-
$$f(x)=|x-1|+x^2$$
The question was to comment on the monotonicity of the function-

**What I tried-**
This was a 2 part question, first part was to comment on continuity and derivability of the function, I found that function was continuous everywhere but was not derivable on $x=1$.


The only proof I know for checking monotonicity is by considering the derivative of function. But here I am confused that how will we check when the function in not derivable at certain points.
I also tried calculating $f'(x)$ by-
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ but couldn't get anywhere. Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I would define the function piecewise  with cases $x\ge 1,x<1$

Comment: Ah that would make it so easy, I feel so dumb, thank you so much.

Comment: If in doubt draw a diagram ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering monotonicity, you don't so much care where the derivative is $0$ so much as where the derivative is positive or negative. Finding the points where the derivative is $0$ is simply a way of figuring out where a possible sign change might occur. Similarly, if the derivative is undefined at an isolated point, you can just treat it as a possible point where the derivative might change sign.

That is, in your case, calculating $f'$, we get
$$f'(x) = \frac{|x - 1|}{x - 1} + 2x = \begin{cases} 2x - 1 & \text{if }x < -1 \\ 2x + 1 &\text{if }x > 1,\end{cases}$$
which is never $0$, so just test the sign of $f'$ on either side of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\ge1$ we have:
$$f\left(x\right)=x-1+x^{2}$$
since $x\ge1$, you can easily see its increasing. Now if $x<1$ we have:
$$f\left(x\right)=-\left(x-1\right)+x^{2}=x^{2}-x+1$$
This case is less intuitive, especially for smaller values of x (since $x^{2}\le x$ for $x\in\left[0,1\right]$). so we derive the function:
$$f'\left(x\right)=2x-1$$
which is positive for every $x\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

Considering both cases, we conclude that f is increasing $\forall x\ge\frac{1}{2}$